# Download Bitbucket repository but guarantee file name is master.zip

Tags: wordpress, download, bitbucket

We have a bitbucket repository we are using as a host for a custom plugin on WordPress. When we push to the master branch it means the plugin is ready to be updated. Currently the WordPress updates work, but I noticed that the way BitBucket downloads repositories is that it names the zip something like this: `teamName-repoName-commitID.zip` and what we need to do is have the name be static, otherwise WordPress thinks it is downloading a new plugin instead of updating an existing one. Is there a way to get the download from BitBucket to be a static name like `master.zip` or `teamName-repoName.zip` without including the commit in the file name?

Comment: Why not download it with one name and then rename it, or use some download software that can rename it during the download? Either of those techniques would work around the apparently-terrible software you are using without having to fix that apparently-terrible software...

Comment: We can't download it and rename it because the download process we use is automatic, it's part of the WordPress Plugin Updater system. WordPress expects that the plugin directory name (in this case, the .zip name) be the same, and BitBucket changes the name of the download based on the most recent commit. So changing it or using a third party software isn't an option for us.

Comment: Well, unfortunately, it's Bitbucket (not Git) that's *generating* the name, so you have two pieces of software that refuse to talk to each other. You'll have to change one of them, or insert a third one.